# Web Api 2 XmlSerializer issue

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a MVC Web Api 2 controller that takes a complex type 'Project' as the only param. The project object should be passed to the controller in XML format in the request body. The XML will look like this:

```
<Project>
   <Name>Test Project</Name>
   <Type>Test Type</Type>
   <Area>Europe</Area>
   ...
```

The 'Project' class itself was generated: at first I had a sample XML file, which I used to generate a corresponding schema. From the schema I generated the Project class using the xsd.exe tool. It looks pretty much like this:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.18020")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class Project {

    private string areaField;
    public string Area {
        get {
            return this.areaField;
        }
        set {
            this.areaField = value;
        }
    }
    ...
```

I tested the Serialization/Deserialization using XmlSerializer as described [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#testing_object_serialization) - they both work fine and produce similar XML to what I use to generate the schema.

Also, I've configured my app in Global.asax to use XML Serialization:

```
var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

However, when I POST the sample Xml to the controller it seems it is still using the default formatter, as it is complaining about missing namespace, and when I add the ns it complains about the missing fields:

> 'EndElement' 'Project' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyNamespace' is not expected. Expecting element 'areaField'.

The only way I can make the cotnroller work is to generate XML in a format acceptd by the Default Serializer and pass it in the request body. Such XML is accepted, which makes me think that the XmlSerialzier is not used. If that is the case what do I have to do to enable it?

Comment: What you have described should be sufficient to enable the XMLSerializer.  I suggest turning on the tracing to see if it will show you what is going wrong in the deserialization process.  What content-type are you sending in the request header?

Comment: Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8